# Best practices: Clarity vs. confidence in code behavior

Tags: coding-style

When reviewing code, I sometimes see blocks like this (I happen to be using a JavaScript since it is widely understood):

```js
if (!myVar || myVar === null || myVar === undefined) {
   ...
}
```

Those who know JavaScript decently well will immediately recognize that `myVar === null` and `myVar === undefined` will never be true if they are evaluated, because if `myVar` is either null or undefined, execution will proceed immediately to the first line inside the if block.

Some might argue that the code above provides greater clarity than simply using `if (!myVar) ...`,
and junior developers may spend less time interpreting it. And clarity in code is obviously paramount. But I find this type of code distasteful, since in my view it promotes a low-confidence approach to software development. And I hardly think I would be alone in that.

Conversely, I can think of times when I have passed an options object to an obscure function with what I know are the function's default values. This is another example of unnecessary verbosity for the sake of clarity, and it does potentially discourage developers (including me) from being confident and clear-eyed about how the function works. But I subjectively find this more acceptable, since the functionality I'm leveraging is more obscure.

All aspects of code exist somewhere on the continuum of common-to-obscure. So the right approach to what I'm calling "clarity vs. confidence" is probably somewhere on a continuum as well. But developers who write and review code in the real world need to know where to place themselves and their teams on that continuum.

My Google search terms didn't turn up much on this topic. Have published experts in coding best practice explored when to write "unnecessary" code vs. not?

---

There can be value in crowd-sourcing opinions, but StackExchange discourages questions that elicit opinion-based answers. Only an answer that includes citations will be selected as the "best answer".

Comment: If the JS engine changes the behavior of `!myVar` in the future then would it cause issues for your code? Likewise for your code being executed by an older engine.

Comment: reading `if (A || B)` seems to communicate to me, the reader, that if `!A` then `B` is still possible (otherwise, why bother mentioning `B` at all?). Writing `!A || A === null` violates this maxim and leaves me confused, double-guessing my knowledge of JS semantics

Comment: Consider switching your checks to exclusively using combinations of `===` and `typeof`. Better yet: `if (var ?? true)` does it for both `null` & `undefined`.

Comment: Juniors not understanding is not an excuse for longer coding, if you dont teach them, they will never understand

Comment: My 2 cents: "I can think of times when I have passed an options object to an obscure function with what I know are the function's default values. This is another example of unnecessary verbosity for the sake of clarity" - you can also see it as a symptom; an indication that the function itself *was unclear*, or more broadly, that the code in that part of application was factored in a way that didn't make enough conceptual sense to the reader. Striving for *that* kind of clarity is, IMO, more important than worrying about `if (!something)` being unclear.

Comment: And 2 more cents: I don't think there is a prescriptive universal answer to where you should be on the "clarity vs. confidence" continuum, as this will heavily depend on the skill level of the people in your team, and also might change over time. Understand who your audience is, then write for them, and help them improve their skill level and conceptual understanding if you can.

Comment: You should just use a function, such as `if (!well_formatted(myVar))` (I'll let you think of a much better name). This is declarative, not imperative. It makes the intent perfectly clear. Besides, I bet the current approach is WET across the codebase.

Comment: Have you tried peer review?

Comment: As an aside: I wish more people knew about `myVar == null`, which covers both `null` _and_ `undefined`, and is much clearer and safer, in my opinion, than `!myVar` which can quickly trip you up with also filtering out `0` and `''`, which might be valid values. Personally, I like to enable the [strict-boolean-expressions](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/) rule in my eslint-config for this reason.

Comment: I think you should become more familiar with your colleagues and their skill levels. Send them a link to this question.

Answer (score 64):

If you can't trust me to figure out what `!myVar` does then either teach me

```
if (!myVar) { // if null or undefined
   ...
}
```

Or don't

```
if (myVar === null || myVar === undefined) {
   ...
}
```

Trying to do both at the same time will just leave me more confused.

If I don't know what `!myVar` does seeing the rest of your code doesn't tell me what it does. It just tells me there's also more stuff going on to worry about. That just adds to the intimidation.

---

To prove that point I offer the comments of [Doc Brown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/440887/best-practices-clarity-vs-confidence-in-code-behavior/440888?noredirect=1#comment968183_440888) & [Jon Wolski](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/440887/best-practices-clarity-vs-confidence-in-code-behavior/440888?noredirect=1#comment968195_440888) that point out the equivalent code is actually:

```
if ( myVar === null 
  || myVar === undefined 
  || myVar === false 
  || Number.isNaN(myVar)
  || myVar === 0 
  || myVar === ""
) {
    ...
}
```

Which I didn't even spot. So don't underestimate how confusing this code is.

---

That means the comment I added is not equivalent even if it was your intent. I could try to fix that but generally I find comments that tell me what code does distasteful.  Mostly because code will get refactored and the comment wont and now I really hate you.

Better comments tell me why it's doing what it's doing. Show me your intent. Help me understand that and you'll free up the brain cells I need to do a web search and learn this standard stuff for myself.

Consider:

```
//Set default if needed
```

Tell me that and I know what you're trying to do even if your code is wrong.

Comment: I was kind of thinking that presenting a simple, confident `if (!myVar)` might be a subtle way of saying, "I want you to be comfortable with this kind of syntax. If you aren't, your current skill level could pose a risk to the project, and you need to be doing web searches early and often to mitigate those risks." To your point, I guess that might make me a bit intimidating at times. And that probably is not the goal. :)

Comment: Why would one write this comment `// if null or undefined` ? Comments are there to explain what's supposed to happen, not to teach the language. Does `i++; // increment i's value by one` make any sense to you?

Comment: @Haukinger Because it's better then writing i++, --i, i=i+1; because you want to teach people what i++ does. But please read the rest of the answer before assuming I condone comments that explain how code works.

Comment: @candied_orange I get your point, `i++; i--; i=i+1;` is even worse :-) `i++;` without a comment is better though. Only topped by a _useful_ comment like `i++; // count a hit`. Even better: `hitsReceived++;`

Comment: @Haukinger You'll find my take on name length [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/315968/131624).

Comment: @EricDuminil https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxi0ETwDvws (mild swearing)

Comment: @BЈовић Explicitness is NOT "noise."

Comment: @ErikE a redundant comment IS noise. this is a textbook example of a redundant comment (`if (some condition) // if some condition`)

Comment: @Haukinger which I'll take over redundant code. But do please read the rest of the answer. I direct your attention to the first paragraph after the second horizontal line.

Comment: @Haukinger Oh, was he referring to the comments? Believe me, I am against comments more than most. But if he was referring to converting the `!myVar` into explicit code checking the values wishing to be excluded... that is not noise. I may have misunderstood what he meant.

Comment: @ErikE If you mean me. My first step was to convert redundant code into a redundant comment. Next I argued for a better comment that was about intent. Unfortunately that came after a peek into the abyss as I foolishly tried to reimplement !MyVar without regard to intent.

Comment: @candied_orange No, I like all that you said. I hate truthy/falsy in JavaScript. When I'm reading or reviewing code it *always* makes me stop and spend extra time to figure out if it's right or what it's actually excluding and if that could cause bugs in the future (such as improperly excluding 0 or '' when it shouldn't). I totally agree that a comment is better than nothing, but the comment SUCKS in favor of simply being explicit. Actually, use TypeScript with explicitness and you get a lot of clarity. :)

Comment: "tell me why it's doing what it's doing" - I wish more people would write comments this way. It's really depressing when I try figuring out some piece of open source code, and the entirety of the 1000 lines I'm looking at goes `const x = 5; // set x to 5` (yes, this exists, and in more than one repo, and on insanely involved specialist code). Meanwhile I'm spending 8 hours trying to figure out why the hell that code exists in the first place.

Comment: @aggregate1166877 that’s an embarrassingly common problem. Now imagine it on every line. I once [asked](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/336430/131624) how to fight that in a coding standards document. This is why we have code reviews. Not just a pile of clueless tools.

Comment: Commenting in such way worst thing ever! Developers shall read and understand code not comments.

Comment: @PaulWasilewski which way?  We’ve talked about at least 3 ways. Did you read the whole answer?

Answer (score 27):

I think [candied_orange's answer](/a/440888/267185) explains why there's a lot of begging the question on your concept of clarity with respect to the particular problem you've chosen, however I think this user went "x ⟶ y" problem in the wrong direction some ways (too honed in on a Y behind the very specific example you gave).

If I understand correctly, to your core issue, away from the particular piece of code you've provided above:

> **All aspects of code exist somewhere on the continuum of common-to-obscure. So the right approach to what I'm calling "clarity vs. confidence" is probably somewhere on a continuum as well**. But developers who write and review code in the real world need to know where to place themselves and their teams on that continuum.

You're talking about using and not necessarily abusing language features, and with respect to their clarity, when you should feel the need to redundantly comment or write code that's unnecessary in a given context, i.e. overexplain what you do in fear that the user won't understand what is going on.

This is complicated, but I've crafted roughly three criteria (of which none is objective) which can aid in helping you understand when to put in-code helpers for certain usage of features.

- Discoverability - how easy is it for users to figure out the language feature you're using.
- How complicated what you're doing is.
- How confusing it can be.

#### Discoverability

I use C++ a lot, and C++ has a lot of features people who regularly use C++ are often simply not familiar with. For example, C++ has lambdas/anonymous functions, in the syntax

```
[reference or value, captures...](parameters,...){
    definition. 
};
```

I've had co-workers who simply did not know about the existence of this feature.  However simply asking me "what is this thing" will result in me saying "That's a C++ lambda".  I may or may not need to go into more specifics on *what that is*, but they now have enough information, by the mere fact of me giving a name to this concept, for them to figure the rest out on their own.  This knowledge is also **self proliferating** as in **just because I wrote code that used this feature, doesn't mean I'm the sole proprietor of information on how to use it**. If, lets say, co-worker Alice, who just learned this feature, is asked by Bob, what this is, Alice can confidently explain what this is to Bob. I wasn't needed.

This applies to a lot of things in JavaScript, such as 'Promises' or the DOM, closures even.  If it doesn't require you to do anything other than point them to the feature and you aren't using in non-obvious ways, than it is at least discoverable.

#### Complexity

Complex problems sometimes require complex solutions.  Even if those solutions use fairly simple constructs built into a language, their usage, even in seemingly obvious in their application, may still need to be explained.

C++ has the concept of "const", where, given a simple variable, if declared `const Type foo` the type is not allowed to have non const operations applied to it, simplified, you cannot mutate a simple const variable.

Except there are several escape hatches to this rule. One escape hatch I've *actually* used, is [`mutable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/mutable).   What `mutable` does is effectively say "this member variable, in this object? Yeah you can just use that in a const context".  Now, why would I do this?  Some times, objects have the semantics of things that are not modified, but the underlying implementation actually does modify said object.  The biggest reason I use this are for network socket API objects, such as ZMQ.  Even sending data technically modifies the socket.  Yet semantically, I'm not really modifying anything the user cares about. This prevents users from doing things they ought to be able to. Similarly, multithreaded primitives, such as mutexes, and atomic variables used for signalling, often have similar "yeah, technically this is mutating the object, but what I'm doing is not semantically a mutation that the user cares about".

But I can't just slap a few `mutable`s on some network sockets and [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and call it a day.  Technically they could just look it up.   But no one would understand **why** I'm doing this.  Alice, in the above example, wouldn't be able to explain to Bob what purpose mutable is serving just by me telling her what it is. I'd have to come in and explain it.  This would confuse even experienced programmers.

So instead of letting that scenario play out, I comment on mutable variables justification for why they are mutable (and often what mutable does).   What I'm doing is *complicated*, it's **not immediately obvious what is happening just by virtue of using this feature and understanding it**.

#### Confusion

A feature may exist in the language, may be discoverable, and may be easy to use.  But that feature (or the allowance of something being written) may still lead to *confusion*.

By confusion, I mean a lot of things, but particularly I mean when you write one thing, and even given simplicity, and discoverability, it still could be interpreted to mean something else. **This is particularly pertinent when you are relying on the language to do something implicitly for you with out clearly expressing intent**.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

I've already introduced you to the idea of const objects. In C++ particular, we like to make objects const whenever we can.  We can also make *references* to objects const (aka semantic immutability), so that when I pass a non-const object to a function, I don't have to copy its data, and I still can enforce the invariants of whether or not that object is changed.

But even with out the escape hatches, you can still accidentally have mutability exposed in const objects.  If you have a pointer to an object, in a C++ object, say:

```
struct Foo{
    int* my_int_ptr; 
    //despite mutating bar, I can still apply const to this function. 
    void baz() const{
        //de referncing the pointer, and adding to it. 
        (*my_int_ptr) += 1; //mutates the object.  
    }

    void mut_qux(); //won't work when Foo is const.
    void const_qux() const; //will work when Foo is const. 
}
```

you can actually have `const` member functions/methods that mutate the underlying object in the pointer. The reason C++ allows this, is that the object only stores the **address** of `my_int_ptr`, not the object, so technically, you are not editing the top level object at all, only the value with in the address. But most people, including myself, expect the semantics of const to cover this use case, to prevent such types of mutability.

Instead of calling this method const, when it technically is in C++, I instead don't use const.  I could, and it would be right, and it wouldn't even be difficult to understand why I could do that.  Every one should understand const doesn't apply to modifying values *within* a pointer right?  But it's **confusing**.  We we say const, we *would like* there to be no *interior* mutability either.

##### Confusion Part 2: Sometimes the Language is Wrong.

One concept I want to introduce here is that languages can *also be wrong*, and that can lead to confusion.  What I mean is there can be features that were ill thought out, shouldn't be there in the first place, and not just non applicable like the above.  As a JavaScript programmer, you should be more intimately familiar with these kinds of failures than I, but here's an example of failures in C++.

In C++, we can write brace-less versions of many types of statements, like `if`, `for`, etc...  The immediately following statement becomes the block. However this is... confusing at best.  Many code bases explicitly outlaw this kind of thing.  It's not always obvious what a statement even is, and it's easy to accidentally edit it such that it is no longer a single statement.

In C++, we also have "simple" type automatic integer/float promotion rules.  However... they are implicit, and they interfere with the type system in some very dangerous ways.  Relying on this system is also confusing, because even if you understand that most things promote to `int` when they are smaller than that, and floats are by default doubles.  It's almost never clear what type will end up what, even when you [use the *same* types](https://godbolt.org/z/WsEMcKcz1), let alone different ones, compared to what *makes sense*. These rules are discoverable, often simple enough, yet lead to a lot of *confusion*.

#### Your example.

If we go ahead and come back around to your actual example, and apply these principles, there's a problem with every point I bring up, especially on confusion and complexity.

First, the rules surrounding negation in JavaScript on variables are not easy to find, and ironically are harder to find than `!!` because of how easy it is to discern for Google "*What does !! mean in JavaScript*", versus the former (my search results did not include anything useful in the first page until I changed my query to include "bang operator" instead of !, but that could just be my personalized results).  But this isn't nearly as big of a deal as the next issue.

Second, **it's really confusing**. Most people, even in JavaScript, expect `!` to correspond to boolean logic ([even MDN shows describes it as "logical not" and shows a boolean example immediately](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)). **This isn't about knowledge, its' about communication**.  So when you're using it for multiple things, even if you *can*, people don't understand what's going on.  If you were to explain to Alice what `!` means in JavaScript, before throwing up, she would not be able to explain to Bob why that line of code's *intent* was. This is really similar to my integer promotion thing.  Like `!`, integer promotions rules are ubiquitous and not new.  But they still lead to all sorts of confusion and problems for people down the line when you rely on the feature instead of explicitly casting types.

The linked answer goes over what you can do.  Comment, etc... Additionally I would argue that there's some other things at play here. First I would argue that JavaScript using `!` like it does is not necessarily the best **language** decision.  I'm not sure we should be relying on JavaScript's mistakes in the first place. JavaScript has an ecosystem of very basic libraries that exist for the sole reason to correct for these mistakes.  Regardless, let's say you're using this in order to figure out if a parameter is really missing or not, this is still functionality often taken from a library.

Instead of using this behavior directly, I would either use a library, or push this behind another function (such as `parameterOptional(your_var, false)` or `parameterExists(your_var)`or `parameterMissing(your_var)`) and then comment the code appropriately *in that function* such that no one really has to deal with it.

Third, What you are doing *may be complex*. If you're actually testing for existence of a value *you may not be trying to test for `!x`, but literally everything except if `x` is true*.  If you're relying on the fact that say, `!x` evaluates true/false *as well* as multiple types of null-ability, then that should be explained.  There are two complex semantic ideas at play despite the code being looked at being incredibly tiny.  If you tried to explain this in a comment, what would it look like?  If it turned out really big, that might give you a clue on the issues with this piece of code.

Some times code can be truly miniscule, but have a lot of implications, and rely on a lot of behavior unsaid.

Comment: I started to write some of this but you did a better job than I was doing--feeling a strong urge to explain yourself is a _code smell_, but sometimes the smell is coming from somewhere adjacent to your code rather than your actual code (like the language or the business logic, which are both things you may not be able to realistically improve--or even a smell that your company needs to invest more in training, if you feel like your teammates are still largely on the unconscious incompetence rung of the ladder and won't realize that they don't know what they're doing).

Comment: Re "confusion": Also consider that what the compiler/language does implicitly can differ between language versions. Any time you're relying on complex implicit behavior, it can be very confusing to people accustomed to using a different language version (like those folks who will be maintaining this code 15 years from now).

Comment: I largely agree with the general message of this answer. *But* I have to note that the broader concept of ["truthiness"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116883/is-truthiness-a-legitimate-programming-term) versus strict booleans is not exactly uncommon and found in many languages – admittedly, rather in "high level" languages. To people familiar with it, the fact that `!x` can mean multiple things is no more complex/confusing than `x.foo()`, `x + y` and similar meaning multiple things via polymorphism/overloading/….

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Agree, python does this.  But Javascript has a lot more concepts around nullabililty that can be*really* confusing. A lot of those concepts aren't typically used with one another, Python has None,False,Zero,and Empty.  These are not used with one another typically and it's obvious what is being tested at least some of the time, though many of these are not idiomatically tested through "truthiness" even in python. Also in python you usually use truthiness, as opposed to "falseyness" seen here.  So even when languages use more than boolean truth don't have the same issues.

Answer (score 21):

##### Use tests to enshrine confidence and intent

If code pushed into production contains redundant statements, it's an indicator of deficiencies in the automated tests which should be taking care of this instead.   Furthermore, a good static code analysis tool should also detect this and warn to remove redundant and unreachable code.

Anything a programmer may be able to infer by reading code is less conclusive than something a test can prove by running it, since humans can misread code whereas a test-runner cannot.

Lastly, there is no need to antagonise clarity and confidence against each other since tests can provide both.

Based on the JavaScript example:

```js
function foo(bar) {
    if (!bar) {
        return "woof";
    } else {
        return "meow";
    }
}
```

Example using Jest:

```js
describe(
    'Foo', () => {
        it.each([0, false, null, undefined])(
            'should return woof', 
            value => expect(foo(value)).toEqual("woof")
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Being a test-oriented person, I like this approach in theory. In practice, I don't know any junior devs who read tests before they read prod code, while troubleshooting. :P

Comment: I’m a big proponent of reading working tests to understand the code. If your jr devs don’t then encourage them.

Comment: @MatthewSouther I have to agree with candied_orange on this, I would make it a priority as part of their on-boarding to teach junior devs a test-focused mindset and have them treat it as a standard part of their workflow (This is something the organisation I work for does anyway - we use our automated tests to help all new-starters, including juniors/graduates, learn the code).   Personally I would consider it a fundamental prerequisite skill for getting 'real' work/tickets merged in, with the same importance as knowing how to use source control and knowing how to use their IDE/debugger.

Comment: And by making the junior devs read these tests they get a better understanding of what tests they're about to break as they make changes. Which is good because sometimes a red test simply needs to die. The sooner you see that the better. Ideally while it's still green.

Comment: And good riddance, if that's the complexity of the code to test the code above it then I pray to the gods I'll never have to write JS to win my bread.

Answer (score 10):

There are two parts to this question.

First, the decision to use `!myVar` versus testing for null or undefined is an issue of teaching the idioms of a language to new developers. Your first code example is an easy answer for JavaScript: use `!myVar` unless you need to treat null and undefined values differently. If you don't, new developers need to learn this JavaScript idiom, and use `!myVar`. Developers will find this in so many libraries and other snippets of JavaScript code that they will have a difficult time in general without knowing this.

The second answer involves this:

> Conversely, I can think of times when I have passed an options object to an obscure function with what I know are the function's default values. This is another example of unnecessary verbosity for the sake of clarity, and it does potentially discourage developers (including me) from being confident and clear-eyed about how the function works. But I subjectively find this more acceptable, since the functionality I'm leveraging is more obscure.

Passing arguments that are the default values to a function isn't bad, nor is it inherently good. Specifically for options objects, passing an empty/default object might be done because some higher level function or object already defines an options object that consumers of your code can customize. For instance, say your object has `this.options` which just happens to default to an empty object `{ }`, which also happens to be the default "options" parameter in the function. Consumers of your code might pass in their own custom `this.options`, which means blindly calling `someFunction(this.options)` is clearer than:

```
if (this.options) {
    someFunction(this.options);
}
else {
    someFunction();
}
```

On the other hand, calling `someFunction({ })` just because the options argument is the default is just cluttering up the code — potentially making the code *less* clear. Other developers need to learn the API. This is not your responsibility. Let's not forget that checking `arguments.length` is a means of supporting function overloads in JavaScript, so be aware that `someFunction({ })` and `someFunction()` might execute different behavior. Again, this is about learning the API, which is something each developer is responsible for.

You are correct that this exists on a continuum. There is no single best way to do this. Developers should learn the well-known idioms of the languages they work in, and they need to learn the APIs of the library code used in the application. Of course, an idiom being "well-known" is also subjective. An idiom for one generation of developers might not be an idiom for another. These things tend to change over time, however I doubt your example of checking `!myVar` versus comparing to null or undefined is an idiom that will change in JavaScript unless the language itself changes.

Comment: _Your first code example is an easy answer for JavaScript: use !myVar unless you need to treat null and undefined values differently._ => Except that `!myVar` is also true for various _other_ values: false, 0, NaN, the empty string, etc...

Comment: @MatthieuM. - that is precisely my point. Typically `!myVar` is shorthand for testing those other falsey values, which is an idiom that JavaScript developers need to understand.

Comment: To expound on your second point: explicitly passing options tells the reader "I want these specific options and I'm passing them for a reason". Whether they happen to be the defaults is irrelevant. Passing no options says "I don't have strict requirements, I'm trusting the defaults are sensible enough". That conveys a *lot* of information about intent, and can be very misleading if you do it one way but mean the other,

Answer (score 7):

You're overthinking this.

> Those who know JavaScript decently well

That will be *anyone competent* who's worked with it regularly for 6-12 months and then they qualify for basically the rest of their career. Why are you trying to optimize for the transient instead of the steady state?

If they're *not* competent they aren't going to know it decently well, even if they've been working with it for the better part of a decade, but you aren't going to fix that by being extra explicit.

And once they do know JS decently well, as you yourself point out your code example violates the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment): it's going to look odd at best to an experienced JS developer.

Answer (score 6):

A reader will assume code are written a certain way for a reason. If the code contains things which does not make logical sense (like a clause which is never evaluated), a reader will assume either they don't understand the code or that there is a bug. In either case the reader will waste time investigating further.

If you want to be explicit you should also be consistent. E.g. if the purpose of the first clause is to check for empty string, you should write it outright:

```
if (myVar === "" || myVar === null || myVar === undefined) {
   ...
}
```

This code is completely unambiguous and the intention is clear.

Comment: A problem with languages like Javascript which have lots of weird and quirky corner cases is that even if someone reading a piece of code will know how the language will process various corner cases, it will often be far from obvious whether the person wrote the code to be reliant upon, indifferent to, or erroneously ignorant of, various corner cases.  For example, a construct like `if (!(thing1 <= thing2))` may or may not be equivalent to `if (thing1 > thing2)` in all *relevant* corner cases, and it may or may not behave in intended fashion for all the corner cases that could arise.

Comment: @supercat: That is why you shoudn't write non-obvious code like `(!(thing1 <= thing2))`. A reader will wonder why you didn't write it in the straightforward way - what particular corner case are you special-casing? Instead make the corner cases explicit like `(thing1 > thing2 || isNaN(thing1))` if that is the corner case in question.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you really check for 0 or empty string in the last piece of code?

Comment: there is no way that this code goes through on code review. Senior developers will just think that you dont know what you are doing if you write code like this @JacquesB

Comment: @strix25: Just curious : how would you write it?

Comment: @EricDuminil: That threw me off as well, but I guess JacquesB just wrote an example for the latter case (check for empty string). In other words, the "or" is meant as "(a) check for 0 OR (b) check for empty string [example for case b follows]", not as "check for (0 or empty string)". This is particularly ironic in light of his final sentence, since the code is now unambiguous, but his explanation isn't. :-)

Comment: @Heinzi: Lol, fair point, I edited the text to be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3):

### Use optional static typing

Since you used Javascript as an example : one easy way to increase both clarity and confidence in code would be to use [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) instead.

You don't even *need* to convert anything :

> TypeScript syntax is a superset of ECMAScript 2015 (ES2015)syntax.
> Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program.

You could add valuable information inside the code, e.g. defining what `myVar` should be, and if it's nullable or not:

```
let myVar: number;
myVar = 1;

if (!myVar || myVar == null || myVar == undefined) {
   console.log("Falsy");
}
```

Type hints are available for other dynamically-typed languages, e.g. for Python since [v3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). And if you're using a statically-typed language (e.g. Java, C#, C++, ...), you basically have to specify the type of `myVar`.

### Fail fast

Thanks to the first line of code, it is now clear what `myVar` is allowed to be, and more importantly, what it cannot be. Those lines would all fail during transpiling:

```
myVar = null; # Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
myVar = "test"; # Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
myVar = [1,2,3]; # Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
```

Also, if you forget to assign a value to `myVar`, the `if` would fail with `Variable 'myVar' is used before being assigned.(2454)`.

This means that the `myVar == null || myVar == undefined` check is now provably useless.

### Comments can lie

The advantage of `let myVar: number;` is that it's not a comment. Comments can become outdated:

```
var myNumber = "some_string"; // myNumber is a number
```

### Example

Since Typescript checks your code and types during transpiling, you can now feel more confident, and write clearer, more concise code ([try it online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtgngcgVygIxAJwFwQHZNWgbgChZEV0IBeCARmKIEsAzCAClLwsuoAYBKAN5EIIgMYB7bAGdxoAHTBxAc1YAiAFrpxAQlV9iAXwghgUkBCEiIE6bJALlauOMgAvLbv1EDQA)):

```
let myNumber: number;
myNumber = 1;

if (myNumber == 0){
   console.log("Zero!");
} else {
   console.log("Not zero!");
}
```

or, if you're working with strings:

```
let myString: string;
myString = "test";

if (myString == ""){
   console.log("Empty!");
} else {
   console.log("Not empty!");
}
```

`myString` and `myNumber` are simply not allowed to be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Downvoter: constructive criticism is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!myVar || myVar === null || myVar === undefined) {
   ...
}
```

You cannot possibly get code coverage in a unit test of `myVar === null || myVar === undefined` because it is impossible to write a test that reaches that code.

As a conclusion, that code is superfluous and has to go, because any added benefit that the brevity may have for a exceptionally undereducated reader, is dwarfed by the confusion of the whole team of not getting 100% code coverage of even the simplest of functions.

Comment: With `myVar = 1`, `myVar === null || myVar === undefined` can definitely be reached. `myVar === null || myVar === undefined` cannot be reached *and* true, though, so it's indeed useless. But as far as I can tell, code coverage will look complete because every part of the code can be reached, e.g. with `myVar = 0` and `myVar = 1`. You can check with `myVar = 1; if (!myVar || console.log("HERE") || myVar === null || console.log("HERE") || myVar === undefined || console.log("HERE") || true ||console.log("NOT HERE")) { console.log("...");}`

Comment: I'd be really interested to know if there's a tool which can detect the useless logic. As mentioned above, I'm pretty sure a typical code coverage tool wouldn't. I'd love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Oh well. This is JavaScript.

So first we need to assume that people know what myVar === null and myVar === undefined mean, whether these cases are possible in some situation, and how they should be handled.

Next we look at the ! operator in JavaScript. It checks for a huge number of possible cases: It handles not only null and undefined, it also handles a boolean "false", an integer or floating point "0", a string "empty", a floating point "NaN" and whatever I forgot.

But in reality you would for example assume for example that myVar is a boolean; you want to handle "true" and "false" correctly, null and undefined maybe shouldn't happen but you think treating them as false is unreasonable. myVar shouldn't be a string, neither empty or non-empty, and either situation would be wrong.

You just need to be aware that if (!myVar) ... does the following in this situation: It handles boolean true and false correctly. It handles null and undefined like false; I hope you know that is correct. It handles strings or integers by going either through the "if" or "else" branch, which both don't make sense. So your code just ignores these cases.

How to express your intent is difficult. You could write

```
if (! myVar) // Assume bool, null or undefined
```

or you could write code that says explicitly which cases you are handling. This is a pain in JavaScript. You either assume the type, or probably have some smaller helper functions for each thing you might want to check.

Answer (score 0):

I write only the code that is necessary for the intended logic to be implemented. Clarity comes on its own by avoiding unnecessary stuff.

Code is clear to understand by default as long as it do exactly what its supposed to do to implement the algorithm. Any extra code makes it harder to understand.

In the if-condition presented, the question one should ask is whether a particular check is necessary. What will happen if in absence of the check the line below it is executed, would any harm occur?

Checking whether a variable is null and then also checking whether its a number is absurd. There is no scenario where this would be needed. You check a variable for being null if you want to de-reference it (you expect it to be an object). If you don't want to de-reference the variable, instead perform some numeric operation on it then only you check whether its a number. There is no scenario in which you do both so you never need both the checks.

It may happen that due to some quirky nature of your language a simple check for null is not enough to guarantee error/exception free execution of the de-referencing action you want to perform after the check. Then you put two or three etc checks that are needed to ensure that the variable infact have an object on it.

The point is, your checks must be there only to ensure successful execution of the action you want to perform, nothing more. This itself bring clarity. Putting extra check when they are not needed for execution of algorithm will confuse other readers (programmers) about your intention.

Answer (score -1):

Your code smells ;)

1. There is clear concept [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

*"Don't repeat yourself" (DRY) is a principle of software development aimed at reducing repetition of software patterns, replacing it with abstractions or using data normalization to avoid **redundancy**.*

2. You provide bad programming approach to junior developer. They'll use that approach everywhere.